# How to set focus or add a caret in searchctrl?

Tags: wxpython

I googled for several days but in vain.How to set focus or insert a caret into the searctrl box so that a barcode reader can read data into the box right away?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# encoding: -*- utf-8 -*-

# mpos_panels.py



# Defines the POS_Panel

import wx
import string
from lc_mpos import *
import mpos_db
import config
import dlg_pos_addItem
import mpos_utility

class POS_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(POS_Panel, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

    # Set the fonts for the panel
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    font_1 = wx.Font(20, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    font_2 = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    font_3 = wx.Font(15, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    font_4 = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
    font_5 = wx.Font(13, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
    self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

    # EndSizer will be the parent of vsizer1 and vsizer2
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    endSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # vsizer1 will be the parent of the left wx.Boxsizers
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    vsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    lbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.title = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Point of Sale')
    self.title.SetFont(font_1)
    lbox1.Add(self.title, 0)
    vsizer1.Add(lbox1, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    lbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.search_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Search'+': ')
    self.search_label.SetFont(font_2)
    #self.search_bar = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Enter Barcode', style=(wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER))        
    self.search_bar = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    lbox2.Add(self.search_label, 0, wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 5)
    lbox2.Add(self.search_bar, 1)
    #self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.onFocus)
    self.search_bar.SetFocus()
    #self.search_bar=wx.CallAfter(SetFocus) 
    #self.search_bar = wx.TE_MULTILINE
    self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnClose)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnBarcode)
    #self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCH_BAR_SEARCH_BTN, self.OnBarcode)
    vsizer1.Add(lbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT, 5)
    vsizer1.Add((-1, 2))

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    lbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.product_lc = ProductLC(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|\
                                wx.LC_VRULES|wx.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    lbox3.Add(self.product_lc, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    vsizer1.Add(lbox3, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

    endSizer.Add(vsizer1, 4, wx.EXPAND|wx.RIGHT, 5)


    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # vsizer2 will be the parent of the right wx.Boxsizers
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    vsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    vsizer2.Add((-1, 30))
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    rbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.receipt_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Receipt')
    self.receipt_label.SetFont(font_3)
    self.receipt_num = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_READONLY|\
                                        wx.TE_CENTER)
    rbox1.Add(self.receipt_label, 0, wx.TOP, 5)
    rbox1.Add(self.receipt_num, 1, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 75)
    vsizer2.Add(rbox1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    rbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.sepLine1 = wx.StaticLine(self, -1)
    rbox2.Add(self.sepLine1, 1)
    vsizer2.Add(rbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    rbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.receipt_lc = ReceiptLC(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|\
                                wx.LC_VRULES|wx.BORDER_DEFAULT|wx.LC_HRULES)
    rbox3.Add(self.receipt_lc, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    vsizer2.Add(rbox3, 4, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.static_box = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, 'Sales Summary')
    rbox4 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.static_box, wx.VERTICAL)

    # subbox1 will hold the total label and amount
    subbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.subtotal_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Sub Total')
    self.subtotal_label.SetFont(font_4)
    self.subtotal_amount = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 
                                       style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RIGHT)
    self.subtotal_amount.SetFont(font_4)
    subbox1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, ''), 2)
    subbox1.Add(self.subtotal_label, 2, wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    subbox1.Add(self.subtotal_amount, 2)
    rbox4.Add(subbox1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

    #--#
    subbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.tax_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Sales Tax')
    self.tax_amount = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 
                                       style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RIGHT)
    self.tax_label.SetFont(font_2)
    self.tax_amount.SetFont(font_2)
    subbox2.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, ''), 2)
    subbox2.Add(self.tax_label, 2, wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    subbox2.Add(self.tax_amount, 2)
    rbox4.Add(subbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 10)

    #--#
    subbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    subbox3.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, ''), 2)
    subbox3.Add(wx.StaticLine(self, -1), 4)
    rbox4.Add(subbox3, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP, 10)

    #--#
    subbox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.total_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Total')
    self.total_amount = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 
                                    style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RIGHT)
    self.total_label.SetFont(font_5)
    self.total_amount.SetFont(font_5)
    subbox4.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, ''), 2)
    subbox4.Add(self.total_label, 2, wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    subbox4.Add(self.total_amount, 2)
    rbox4.Add(subbox4, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 10)

    #--#s
    vsizer2.Add(rbox4, 2, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, 5)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    rbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.complete_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Complete Transaction",
                                  size=(-1, 100))
    self.complete_btn.SetFont(font_4)
    self.cancel_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Cancel",
                                   size=(-1, 100))
    self.cancel_btn.SetFont(font_4)
    rbox5.Add(self.cancel_btn, 1, wx.RIGHT, 10)
    rbox5.Add(self.complete_btn, 2)
    vsizer2.Add(rbox5, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 20)
    vsizer2.Add((-1, 5))

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    endSizer.Add(vsizer2, 5, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(endSizer)

    # Set up complimentary objects
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.db = mpos_db.MPOS_DB()
    self.config = config.Configuration()
    self.c_symbol = self.config.cCurrency()[0]
    self.c_dec = self.config.cCurrency()[1]
    self.thous_sep = self.config.ThousandsSep()

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.m1, self.t1, self.m2, self.t2, self.btn_l1 = '', '', '', '', ''
    self.btn_l2, self.r_label, self.t_label = '', '', ''
    self.Language()

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
    #self.PListRefresh()
    self.SetReceiptNo()
    self.SaleInfoSetup()
    self.edit_mode = False
    self.OnCancel(None)

    # Bindings
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnSearch)
    self.product_lc.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelect)
    self.receipt_lc.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnRClick)
    self.receipt_lc.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnEdit)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnComplete, self.complete_btn)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, self.cancel_btn)
    self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_CANCEL_BTN, self.OnSearchCancel)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Function Definitions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#def PListRefresh(self):
    #'Refreshes the Product List'
    #self.product_table = self.db.AllProducts()
    #self.product_lc.DeleteAllItems()

    # Add in table
    #for i in range(0, len(self.product_table)):

        #self.product_lc.InsertStringItem(i, str(self.product_table[i][0]))
        #self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 1, self.product_table[i][1])
        #self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 2, self.product_table[i][2])
        #ins = '%s %.'+str(self.c_dec)+'f'
        #rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, self.product_table[i][3])
        #self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 3, rslt)
        #if i % 2 == 0:
            #self.product_lc.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.LIGHT_GREY)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def SetFocus(self, event):
    print "panel received focus!"

def OnBarcode(self, event):
    # Some form of product look-up here
    barcode = self.searchCtrl.GetValue()

def OnClose(self, event):
    self.Destroy()  


def OnSearch(self, evt):
    '''
    This performs a dynamic search of the products table using the 
    values entered in the search bar.'''

    #try:    
        # Create a list of the terms entered in the search bar
    self.search_text = (self.search_bar.GetValue()).split()

        # Identify any prices in the search apply SQL formatting accordingly
    accept = list(string.digits) + ['.']
    for i in range(0, len(self.search_text)):
        term = self.search_text[i]
        price_type = True
        for ch in term:
            if ch not in accept:
                price_type = False
                break
        if not price_type:
            index = self.search_text.index(term)
            self.search_text[index] = "'%" + term + "%'"
        else:
            self.search_text.append("'%" + term + "%'")

        # Pass the list to the pSearch function in mpos_db.py
    self.product_table = self.db.productSearch(self.search_text)

        # Add in table
    self.product_lc.DeleteAllItems()
    for i in range(0, len(self.product_table)):
            self.product_lc.InsertStringItem(i, str(self.product_table[i][0]))
            self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 1, self.product_table[i][1])
            self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 2, self.product_table[i][2])

            ins = '%s %.'+str(self.c_dec)+'f'
            rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, self.product_table[i][3])
            self.product_lc.SetStringItem(i, 3, rslt)

            if i % 2 == 0:
                self.product_lc.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.LIGHT_GREY)
    self.product_lc.Focus(0)

    #except IndexError, e: # This occurs when the search bar is empty
         #self.PListRefresh()#no search results
    #evt.Skip()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------    

def OnSelect(self, evt):
    'Brings up the dlg_pos_addItem dialog'
    dlg = dlg_pos_addItem.POS_AddItem(self, -1, 'miniPOS')
    # Get the info from the highlighted Item
    self.row = self.product_lc.GetFocusedItem()
    self.selected_info = []
    for column in range(4):
        item = self.product_lc.GetItem(self.row, column)
        self.selected_info.append(item.GetText())
    # Extract the float from the price column to pass
    self.selected_info[3] = float(((self.selected_info[3]).split(' '))[-1])
    # Set the info for the dlg
    dlg.SetInfo(self.selected_info)
    rslt = dlg.ShowModal()
    if rslt != wx.ID_CANCEL:
        self.input = dlg.SendInfo()

        if self.input[2] != 0 and not self.input[2]:
            self.m1, self.t1 = '', ''
            self.Language()
            wx.MessageBox(self.m1, self.t1)
            return False
        if not self.input[3] or self.input[3] == '0':
            self.m1, self.t1 = '', ''
            self.Language()
            wx.MessageBox(self.m1, self.t1)
            return False
    else:
        return False

    # Get the index #s, product IDs and prices from the receipt LC
    receipt = []
    item_count = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
    for i in range(item_count):
        index = i
        prod_ID = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 0).GetText()
        prod_price = (self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 2).GetText()).split(' ')
        prod_price = float(prod_price[-1])
        receipt.append((index, prod_ID, prod_price,))

    # Check to see if the product has been added at the same price
    match_boolean = False
    for item in receipt:
        if self.input[0] == item[1] and self.input[2] == item[2]:
            match_boolean = True
            insert_point = item[0]
            break

    # Check if the item was already added to the receipt
    row_count = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
    productId_list = []
    for i in range(row_count):
        item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 0)
        productId_list.append(item.GetText())

    if not match_boolean:
        # Add the returned value to the Receipt list control
        i_point = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
        self.receipt_lc.InsertStringItem(i_point, self.input[0])
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 1, self.input[1])
        ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, self.input[2])
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 2, rslt)
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 3, self.input[3])
    else:
        i_point = insert_point
        item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i_point, 3)
        start_qty = float(item.GetText())
        self.input[3] = str(float(self.input[3]) + start_qty) 
        ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, self.input[2])
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 2, rslt)
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 3, self.input[3])

    # Calculate the Price x Quantity
    price = float(self.input[2])
    quantity = float(self.input[3])
    amount = price * quantity
    ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
    rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, amount)
    self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 4, rslt)
    self.Total()

    # Reset the search bar
    self.search_bar.SetValue('')
    self.PListRefresh()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnRClick(self, evt):
    'Deletes an item from the receipt if it is right clicked'
    row = self.receipt_lc.GetFocusedItem()
    if not self.edit_mode:
        self.receipt_lc.DeleteItem(row)
    else:
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(row, 3, '0')
        rslt = ('%s 0') % self.c_symbol
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(row, 4, rslt)
    self.Total()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnEdit(self, evt):
    'Opens up the edit dialog if an item in the receipt_lc is selected'
    dlg = dlg_pos_addItem.POS_AddItem(self, -1, 'miniPOS')
    # Get the info from the highlighted Item
    self.row = self.receipt_lc.GetFocusedItem()
    self.selected_info = []
    for column in range(4):
        item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(self.row, column)
        self.selected_info.append(item.GetText())
    # Extract the float from the price column to pass
    self.selected_info[2] = float(((self.selected_info[2]).split(' '))[-1])

    dlg.SetInfo2(self.selected_info)
    rslt = dlg.ShowModal()
    if rslt != wx.ID_CANCEL:
        self.input = dlg.SendInfo()

        if self.input[2] != 0 and not self.input[2]:
            self.m1, self.t1 = '', ''
            self.Language()
            wx.MessageBox(self.m1, self.t1)
            return False
        if not self.input[3] or self.input[3] == '0':
            self.m1, self.t1 = '', ''
            self.Language()
            wx.MessageBox(self.m1, self.t1)
            return False
    else:
        return False

    # Add the returned value to the Receipt list control
    i_point = self.receipt_lc.GetFocusedItem()
    self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 1, self.input[1])
    ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
    rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, self.input[2])
    self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 2, rslt)
    self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 3, self.input[3])

    # Calculate the Price x Quantity
    price = float(self.input[2])
    quantity = float(self.input[3])
    amount = price * quantity
    ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
    rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, amount)
    self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i_point, 4, rslt)
    self.Total()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def Total(self):
    'Get all of the amounts from the receipt list control'
    row_count = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
    amounts = []
    for i in range(0, row_count):
        item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 4)
        amounts.append(float(((item.GetText()).split(' '))[-1]))
    sum = 0
    for num in amounts:
        sum += num

    if self.salesTax_on:
        ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, sum)
        rslt = self.TSep(rslt)
        self.subtotal_amount.SetValue(rslt)

        tax = float(sum) * (self.sales_tax/100)
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, tax)
        rslt = self.TSep(rslt)
        self.tax_amount.SetValue(rslt)

        total = sum + tax
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, total)
        rslt = self.TSep(rslt)
        self.total_amount.SetValue(rslt)
    else:
        self.subtotal_amount.SetValue('0')
        self.tax_amount.SetValue('0')
        ins = '%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f'
        rslt = ins % (self.c_symbol, sum)
        rslt = self.TSep(rslt)
        self.total_amount.SetValue(rslt)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------    
'Commit the transaction to the Sales and SaleItems tables'
def OnComplete(self, evt):
    # Get item count
    item_count = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
    if item_count != 0:
        # Get the total amount
        amount = ((self.total_amount.GetValue()).split(' '))[-1]
        amount = float(self.TotalRestore(amount))

        # Get the productIds and qantities from the receipt_lc
        receipt_info = []
        r_len = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(r_len):
            item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 0)
            prod_id = item.GetText()
            item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 2)
            sale_price = item.GetText()
            sale_price = (sale_price.split(' '))[-1]
            item = self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 3)
            quantity = item.GetText()
            receipt_info.append((prod_id, sale_price, quantity))

        if not self.edit_mode:
            # Record the sale and get the saleId
            saleId = self.db.RecordSale(amount)
            if not saleId:
                # If there's a read/write problem, do nothing
                return False
            # Send the productId, SaleId and quantities to be entered in
            #       the soldItems table
            self.db.RecSaleItems(saleId, receipt_info)
            self.receipt_lc.DeleteAllItems()
            self.SetReceiptNo()

        else:
            # Get the Sale Id and Amount
            saleId = ((self.receipt_num.GetValue()).split(' '))[-1]
            amount = ((self.total_amount.GetValue()).split(' '))[-1]
            # Delete the original record in the database
            self.db.DeleteSIRecord(saleId)
            # Update the sale record
            amount = mpos_utility.UnTSep(amount)
            self.db.UpdateSale(saleId, float(amount))
            self.db.RecSaleItems(saleId, receipt_info)

        # Reset the POS screen
        self.OnCancel(None)

    else:
        self.m2, self.t2 = '', ''
        self.Language()
        wx.MessageBox(self.m2, self.t2)
        self.OnCancel(None)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnCancel(self, evt):
    if not self.edit_mode:
        pass
    else:
        self.SetReceiptNo()
        self.btn_l1 = ''
        self.Language()
        self.complete_btn.SetLabel(self.btn_l1)

    self.receipt_lc.DeleteAllItems()
    self.edit_mode = False 
    rslt = ('%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f') % (self.c_symbol, 0.0)
    self.subtotal_amount.SetValue(rslt)
    self.tax_amount.SetValue(rslt)
    self.total_amount.SetValue(rslt)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def SetReceiptNo(self):
    'Sets the receipt number label to the next receiptId number'
    next_saleId = self.db.ReceiptNo()
    self.r_label = ''
    self.Language()
    self.receipt_num.SetValue(self.r_label + ':  ' + str(next_saleId))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def EditModeToggle(self, saleId, receipt_table):
    'Edit a sale record using the POS panel'
    self.btn_l2 = ''
    self.Language()
    self.complete_btn.SetLabel(self.btn_l2)
    self.edit_mode = True 
    self.r_label = ''
    self.Language()
    self.receipt_num.SetValue(self.r_label + ':  ' + saleId)

    # Add in receipt table for editing
    self.receipt_lc.DeleteAllItems()
    for i in range(len(receipt_table)):
        self.receipt_lc.InsertStringItem(i, str(receipt_table[i][0]))
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 1, str(receipt_table[i][1]))
        x = ('%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f') % (self.c_symbol, receipt_table[i][2])
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 2, x)
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 3, str(receipt_table[i][3]))
        x = ('%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f') % (self.c_symbol, receipt_table[i][4])
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 4, x)

    self.Total()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def TotalRestore(self, total):
    total = list(total)
    for i in total:
        if i == ',':
            del total[total.index(i)]
    return ''.join(total)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def SaleInfoSetup(self):
    'Sets up the Sales Info box based on the config info for sales tax.'
    config_info = self.config.SalesTaxInfo()
    if config_info[0] != '1':
        self.salesTax_on = False
    else:
        self.salesTax_on = True

    if self.salesTax_on:
        self.subtotal_label.Enable()
        self.subtotal_amount.Enable()
        self.tax_label.Enable()
        self.tax_amount.Enable()
        self.sales_tax = float(config_info[1])
        self.t_lable = ''
        self.Language()
        self.tax_label.SetLabel(self.t_label+' '+str(self.sales_tax)+' %')
    else:
        self.subtotal_label.Disable()
        self.subtotal_amount.Disable()
        self.tax_label.Disable()
        self.tax_amount.Disable()
        self.subtotal_amount.SetValue('0')
        self.tax_amount.SetValue('0')
        self.sales_tax = 0.0

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def TSep(self, amount):
    'Adds in thousands separator, if toggled'
    if self.thous_sep:
        amount = amount.split(' ')
        pFix = amount[0]
        amount = amount[-1]
        if '.' in amount: 
            amount = amount.split('.')
            sfx = '.' + amount[-1]
            amount = amount[0]
        else:
            sfx = ''
        tSep_cnt = 0        # counts the number of tseps added
        tSep_lst = []       # tells where to insert the tseps
        amount = list(amount)
        amount.reverse()
        for i in range(1, len(amount)):
            if i%3 == 0:
                tSep_lst.append(i + tSep_cnt)
                tSep_cnt += 1
        for i in tSep_lst:
            amount.insert(i, ',')
        amount.reverse()
        return pFix + ' ' + ''.join(amount) + sfx
    else:
        return amount

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def ConfigUpdate(self):
    'Updates the pages after the configuration file is changed'
    self.c_symbol = self.config.cCurrency()[0]
    self.c_dec = self.config.cCurrency()[1]
    self.thous_sep = self.config.ThousandsSep()
    # Update the product list control
    self.PListRefresh()
    # Refresh the current receiept
    row_count = self.receipt_lc.GetItemCount()
    for i in range(row_count):
        # Refresh Prices
        price = ((self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 2)).GetText()).split(' ')
        price = float(price[-1])
        rslt = ('%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f') % (self.c_symbol, price)
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 2, rslt)
        # Refresh Amounts
        amount = ((self.receipt_lc.GetItem(i, 4)).GetText()).split(' ')
        amount = float(amount[-1])
        rslt = ('%s %.'+self.c_dec+'f') % (self.c_symbol, amount)
        self.receipt_lc.SetStringItem(i, 4, rslt)
    # Refresh the total amount
    self.SaleInfoSetup()
    self.Total()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def Language(self):
    'Sets the language.'
    objects1 = [self.title, self.search_label, 
              self.receipt_label, self.static_box, 
              self.subtotal_label, self.tax_label,
              self.total_label, self.complete_btn,
              self.cancel_btn]
    ids1 = 1, 33, 36, 37, 38, 40, 39, 41, 42
    words = mpos_utility.lang(ids1)
    for object, word in zip(objects1, words):
        object.SetLabel(word)

    ids2 = 43, 8, 45, 44, 41, 47, 46, 40
    words = mpos_utility.lang(ids2)
    self.m1, self.t1, self.m2, self.t2 = words[:4]
    self.btn_l1, self.btn_l2 = words[4:6]
    self.r_label, self.t_label = words[6:]

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnSearchCancel(self, evt):
    '''When the search bar Cancel button is pressed, this function 
    clears the search bar value and updates the product list.'''
    self.search_bar.SetValue('')
    self.PListRefresh()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that `wx.SearchCtrl` existed but you can simply use `SetFocus` apparently without issue.
That is, of course, unless I have interpreted your question incorrectly.

```
import wx
product_details = {'11111':['Product 1','ISBN: 2312313231-213213123-1','Publisher: John Hopkins'],
                '22222':['Product 2','ISBN: 45454541-213213123-1','Publisher: John Smith'],
                '33333':['Product 3','ISBN: 26557575-213213123-1','Publisher: Moonbeam','Author: Bill Shakespeare'],
                }

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title)
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.something = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Entry prior to search")
        self.searchCtrl = wx.SearchCtrl(self.Panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Enter Barcode",style=(wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER))
        self.textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Product information",
            style = (wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY))

        boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        boxSizer.Add(self.something, proportion = 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        boxSizer.Add(self.searchCtrl, proportion = 0)
        boxSizer.AddSpacer(10)
        boxSizer.Add(self.textCtrl, proportion = 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.searchCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnBarcode)
        self.searchCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN, self.OnBarcode)

        self.Panel.SetSizer(boxSizer)
        self.searchCtrl.SetFocus()

    def OnBarcode(self, event):
        # Some form of product look-up here
        barcode = self.searchCtrl.GetValue()
        if barcode in product_details:
            self.textCtrl.Clear()
            for item in product_details[barcode]:
                self.textCtrl.write(item+'\n')
        else:
            self.textCtrl.SetValue("Unknown barcode")

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
top = MyFrame("My Window")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: TKs Rolf. I am a programmer with a leaner plate. I downloaded an open source POS and wanted to make changes. There are too many boxes. I just can't add focus to the search bar.....

Comment: @dxxchung It looks as if you have been hacking about in the code. There is no `wx.SearchCtrl` in there. There is however something called `search_bar` which is a `wx.TextCtrl` and already has a `Bind` on `wx.EVT_TEXT`. I would suggest that you start again with the original code, because as it is, you have a created a confusing mess.

Comment: I cleared up everything. It did not add focus at all.     excerpt:  lbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        
        self.search_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Search'+': ')
        self.search_label.SetFont(font_2)
        self.search_bar = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)
        self.search_bar.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnFocus)
        lbox2.Add(self.search_label, 0, wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 5)
        lbox2.Add(self.search_bar, 1)
        
        vsizer1.Add(lbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT, 5)
        vsizer1.Add((-1, 2))

Comment: @dxxchung I am glad to hear that you have resolved your problem. Happy coding!